# Convert an api result set to a c# Object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am calling an API to get a set of assignment data as JSON.  I would like to convert that into C# model objects and display the results in my MVC view. Here is my code so far that successfully brings back the results, now I need it converted to an assignment Model (i.e I need API response.content turned into assignment).

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ViewResult> Index()
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    HttpRequestMessage apiRequest = CreateRequestToService(HttpMethod.Get, "api/Assignment/GetAll");

    HttpResponseMessage apiResponse;
    Assignment assignment = new Assignment();

    try
    {
        apiResponse = await HttpClient.SendAsync(apiRequest);
    }
    catch
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    if (!apiResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    var result = apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   var results = ???
    return View( results);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need API response.content turned into assignment

Convert the content of the response to the desired type. Lets assume it is a collection of the models

```
//...

var assignments = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Assignment>>();

//...
```

Comment: I was able to display using this code 
               var assignmentAnswer = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync< List<Assignment>>();

Comment: @Curious-programmer updated to match. works the same. Was not sure whether you were converting one type to the assignments or if they already coming from the response as that type.